# Trying to build a vocabulary trainer with a hashtable

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

Maybe this is the wrong approach but I try to build a simple vocabulary database using a Hashtable where I run into two problems.

First of all, if I have for several topics an own hashtable, can I list all the hashtables-names and how? Maybe in a loop? I was not able to figure out, to list the hashtables.

Secondly, I tried to put hashtables into a hashtable which somehow works but I still need to figure out if I am allowed to do so, or that is a wrong approach? Please have a look at the below examples.

(This is only for personal use and for me to learn more about Powershell but also a kind of a challenge to myself), any other suggestions are welcome.

I was trying around and experimenting but was not able to find any solution.
I also tried to do something with Arrays but also no success. Maybe there is a solution with either Hashtables or arrays or there is even something better for such an approach?

```
$Vocabulary = @{

$Weekdays = [ordered]@{Monday = 'Montag';Tuesday = 'Dienstag';Wednesday = 'Mittwoch'}
$Months = [ordered]@{January = 'Januar';February = 'Februar';March = 'März'}

}
```

If possible I would like to be able to loop through all Hashtables within the Hashtable and receive their names. Using the above example, the output should be:

$Weekdays
$Months

I am able to find the keys and the values but to search for the name of the hashtable itself is my challenge here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hashtable instantiation is using uninitialized variables for hashtable keys. If you do this:

```
$Weekdays = [ordered]@{Monday = 'Montag';Tuesday = 'Dienstag';Wednesday = 'Mittwoch'}
$Months = [ordered]@{January = 'Januar';February = 'Februar';March = 'März'}

$Vocabulary = @{ "Weekdays" = $Weekdays, "Months"=$months }

$Vocabulary.Keys
```

You will get the desired output

Comment: Thanx Swestner,
That is a nice solution, I like it. This never crossed my line but you never learn out, do you. Thanx a lot, really appreciate your answer,

Comment: Glad I could help! Happy we all have a place like stackoverflow to grow!

Comment: So true, this is a great site with great people and very smart brains ;)